# Grid column responsive width but no more and no less than

Tags: css, css-grid, responsiveness

I would like to have a css grid with cards, that are responsive and can grow and shrink as in these pictures:
[image: small screen - two columns]

[image: larger screen - three columns]

So for this reason I have used `minmax` css function:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));
```

However, if there are no more cards in list to be put in a single row, the existing cards grow to the limits of parent:

[image: only 2 cards - grow indefinitely]

How can I give an upper limit for the minmax function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr))` with `repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr))`

Comment: Great, it works as I want with one exception: 300px is still the minimum width of a grid item, but maximum is not determined. It's fine for me, as the items don't grow if there are less items, but I would like to know the maximum width so that I can create thumbnails with accurate sizes. Do you know how can I calculate the maximum width of an item?

Comment: you can add the max-width you want instead of 1fr
repeat( auto-fill, minmax(300px, 400px)) for example

Comment: It doesn't work, it jest makes them always have the max width

Comment: Found it, the items will expand to maximum 2x min width

Comment: very useful, didn't know that